# How to push two values to the same key from Arduino to Firebase

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I would like to push two values at the same time (to the same node) from arduino to firebase. I tried to create an array and push the array to firebase, however, that is not working.

Here are the two values that I'm pushing, but I would like to push them to the same unique key:

```
temp1 = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
 StaticJsonBuffer<50> jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& timeStampObject = jsonBuffer.createObject();
timeStampObject[".sv"] = "timestamp";

Firebase.push("Sensors/20/temperatures/001", temp1);
Firebase.push("Sensors/20/temperatures/001", timeStampObject);
```

[How it should look like in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS0Wt.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does firebase allow  what you are trying to do?

Comment: I believe so, because you can push an array of values to Firebase.

Comment: i think that you have to push properly formatted JSON data ... push only once

Comment: I tried pushing it only once using an array. However, I don't know how to add a json object to an array.

Comment: [JsonObject::crateNestedArray()](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonobject/createnestedarray/) example may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hcheung thanks for your help! It solved the problem. This is my code now:

```
StaticJsonBuffer<256> jsonBuffer;
JsonArray& array = jsonBuffer.createArray();
array.add(timeStampObject);
array.add(temp1);
Firebase.push("Sensors", array);
```